# If loop not working. When ran it shows duplicate cout.

Tags: visual-c++

I am trying to make a random number generator guessing game, which will allow the user to pick a range. After the range is picked the user will try to guess the number until they get it right. I am new to c++ and do not understand why two cout outputs on screen. I am new to c++ and cant figure out why. I am using visual studio 17.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;



int main()
{
    int userNum;
    char choice;
    int numattempts = 0;
    int randNumber;
    srand(time(0));




cout << "Welcome to the number guessing game\n" << "Please choose what range you want to guess from\n" << " '1' = 0-20\n '2'= 0-50\n '3'= 0-100\n ";
cin >> choice;



if (choice == '1')
{

    randNumber = 0 + rand() % 20;

    cout << "Enter a number between 0 and 20\n";
    cin >> userNum;
    cout << randNumber;


    do {

        if (userNum < randNumber)
        {
            cout << "Number is Higher\n";
            cin >> userNum;
        }

        else if (userNum > randNumber)
        {
            cout << "Number is Lower\n";
            cin >> userNum;
        }

        else (userNum == randNumber);
        {
            cout << "Congrats You got it!\n";

        }

    } while (userNum != randNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you miss another if in the last checking and should not put semicolon there.
try to debug and you'll find that it should be like this

```
do {

        if (userNum < randNumber)
        {
            cout << "Number is Higher\n";
            cin >> userNum;
        }
        else if (userNum > randNumber)
        {
            cout << "Number is Lower\n";
            cin >> userNum;
        }
        else if(userNum == randNumber)
        {
            cout << "Congrats You got it!\n";
        }

    } while (userNum != randNumber);
```

Comment: Oh my gosh I feel dumb. Thank you so much!